# What is HTTP/1.1 0?

Tags: http

So I'm trying to get onto a website I need to work on, but the page isn't loading.

Here's the request headers as copied from Google Chrome:

```
GET http://temailer.co.za/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17
```

Here's the response headers also copied from Google Chrome:

```
HTTP/1.1 0 
HTTP
```

I don't understand what's going on here. Can anyone help/explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> GET http://temailer.co.za/ HTTP/1.1

This is a proxy request; the server you're pointing it at does not allow or support such, and returns the best it does support: an HTTP/1.0 failure.

You did not enter the above in a browser address bar; that's not how HTTP works.

Comment: I entered http://www.temailer.co.za/ in the address bar which generated the GET request that you pasted... If I understand correctly. Oddly enough, rebooting my pc seemed to fix the problem...